# With the help of line number, replace a whole line with another line which cotains file path

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

How do I replace Old_String with New_String in a file?

Old_String:

```
 $result = $client->updateInventory("UpdateInventory.xml");
```

New_String:

```
 $result = $client->updateInventory("/Desktop/new/UpdateInventory.xml");
```

Old_String in line number = 5 in a file called file1.txt

**What I tried:**

```
sed '5s/.*/'$result = $client->updateInventory("/Desktop/new/UpdateInventory.xml");'/' file1.txt
```

Comment: `sed '5s|"|"/Desktop/new/|'` would work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below command to achieve the same

```
sed "5s:.*:'$'result = '$'client->updateInventory('/Desktop/new/UpdateInventory.xml');:g" filename | sed "s:'$':$:g" | tr "'" '"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the inner single quotes. They end the outer ones, so `$result` will get expanded and `sed` will probably complain about an unfinished `s` command.

Instead use a different delimiter for the `s` command, you can use almost anything instead of the slash. So

```
sed '5s_.*_$result = $client->updateInventory("/Desktop/new/UpdateInventory.xml")‌​;_' file1.txt
```

is what you want.

Comment: This solution shows `sed: -e expression #1, char 71: unknown option to `s'`

Comment: It's can't unless your replacement string looks different. Of course, if it contains an underscore, the underscore was a bad choice for the delimiter. Then choose another char as delimiter like `!` or `:` or `#` or ...

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `c` command which clears the line(s) specified by address

```
$ seq 5 | sed '2c\
foobar'
1
foobar
3
4
5

$ # with GNU-sed, assuming \ is not first character
$ seq 5 | sed '2cfoobar'
```

Both `s` and `c` commands will have issues if replacement string has certain special characters, for ex:

```
$ seq 3 | sed '2s/.*/abc&xyz/'
1
abc2xyz
3
$ seq 3 | sed '2cabc\tabc'
1
abc     abc
3
```

A robust way to handle this is to use `r` command

```
$ echo 'foo&\t\n\1///\\xyz' > f1
$ seq 3 | sed -e '2rf1' -e '2d'
1
foo&\t\n\1///\\xyz
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk command also we can achieve the result

---

```
awk  ‘NR==5 {gsub(".*","$result = $client->updateInventory(/Desktop/new/UpdateInventory.xml);",$0);print $0}' filename| sed 's/(/&"/g' | sed 's/)/"&/g'
```

---

Comment: Sorry! it shows `awk: 1: unexpected character '.'`

Comment: will check and update

Comment: Command is  working fine  as tested . 

awk  ‘NR==5 {gsub(".*","$result = $client->updateInventory(/Desktop/new/UpdateInventory.xml);",$0);print $0}' filename| sed 's/(/&"/g' | sed 's/)/"&/g'


Output
$result = $client->updateInventory("/Desktop/new/UpdateInventory.xml");